# How to SFTP into Amazon EC2 Ubuntu t1.micro instance?

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp

I have an amazon aws t1.micro instance set up (Ubuntu).
I can SSH into it but I would like to edit files on it from local machine editor (Mac OS X Mountain Lion) probably with TextWrangler or something.

How can I get access to files on my ec2 t1.micro ubuntu instance?

TIA,
Harshad

Comment: to edit files locally you will have to download them, edit and upload. a better approach would be to SSH into the machine, use either vi or eamcs to edit the files

Comment: I am already doing that but honestly, I am no fan of terminal based editors. I come from Windows world. I would like something like TextWrangler or Sublime Text to edit my EC2 files.

Comment: If you use Filezilla follow this instructions : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9BDvg42-JI
You can use Cyberduck, follow instructions below: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hd4oL3WIPVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like sshfs. SSHFS lets you mount a remote file system and have it show up as a local mount point on your local system.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS

A simple example is:
1. From the client make sure that you have sshfs installed:
  "sudo apt-get install sshfs"
2. From the client system:
  "sudo sshfs user@ubuntuServer:/remote/path /local/path -o allow_other"

This will mount /remote/path on the ubuntu server to /local/path on your machine. The "-o allow_other" says that any user on the client system and read/write to the mount point assuming that the "user@" user has permissions on the ubuntu server to read/write to the "/remote/path".

Comment: Any Mac OS X equivalents?

Comment: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS
It looks like this may work. Sorry, I do not have a osx machine to test it out on.

Comment: I tried using [cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) but it keeps me asking the password for my ubuntu which i can't find anywhere

Comment: On your local system you are either running the sshfs command as root or are using sudo. When you do this the privileged account no longer has access to your ssh key. The easiest thing will be to become root, and then do a ssh-add with the path to the ssh key that you use for ssh'ing to your server.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but I need to speak up: This is a very bad practice.

You should be editing locally, then deploying to EC2. From your description, it sounds like you're editing live on what is essentially a production website.

Yikes!

Comment: I guess I never mentioned that EC2 is my production. I am using EC2 t1.micro instance for development. It is better to connect to the central common environment from multiple platforms I use throughout the day. I have Windows, Mac, Linux local boxes so using EC2 t1.micro for development from any of these boxes happens to be my preference.